# Div animation with transition from image to content

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

I have been trying to replicate an effect that I found in a JS Fiddle but one that suits my website. The JSFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/4p6Lk/9/). I have 5 divs all with this effect, a row of 3 divs and below it a row of 2 divs, there is no text showing up at all.

Below is my code but it does not seem to work in the same way, I have had to include other divs etc for it to work in the environment of my website. But now it will not work. My code is below.

*HTML*

```
<div id="apDiv7">
  <div style="border-radius: 20px;" class="table-wrapper">
    <div class="row row1">
      <div class="column">
        <div class="hover-img">
          <img src="topright.png" width="400" height="300" class="img1"/>
          <p class="text">text here 1</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="hover-img">
          <img src="topcenter.png" width="400" height="300" />
          <p class="text">text here 2</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="hover-img">
          <img src="topleft.png" width="400" height="300" />
          <p class="text">text here 3</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row2">
      <div class="column">
        <div class="hover-img">
          <img src="bottomleft.png" width="600" height="400" />
          <p class="text">text here 4</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="hover-img">
          <p></p>
          <img src="bottomright.png" width="600" height="400" />
          <p class="text">text here 5</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```css
#apDiv7 {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    height: 700px;
    left: 5%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 8px solid #666666;
}
.hover-img {
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    background: url(bbclike/topright.png);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    line-height: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.hover-img:hover{
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(0deg);
    font-size:14px;
    color:white;
}
.hover-img:hover > .text {
    opacity: 1;
}
.hover-img > .text {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 500ms ease-in-out;
}
```

I would be greatful is somebody could help me tweak this code to get it working.

I will delete this live demo before I accept an answer and close the question, this is just to help solve my particular problem. http://www.mildenhire.com/bigsmile/graphic.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="apDiv7">
  <div style="border-radius: 20px;" class="table-wrapper">
    <div class="row row1">
      <div class="column">
        <div class="hover-img img1">
          text here 1
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="hover-img img2">
          text here 2
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="hover-img img3">
          text here 3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row row2">
      <div class="column">
        <div class="hover-img img4">
          text here 4
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <div class="hover-img img5">
          text here 5
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

also specify url for image here

```
.img1 {
  background: green;
}

.img2 {
  background: red;
}

.img3 {
  background: blue;
}

.img4 {
  background: #333;
}

.img5 {
  background: #c33;
}
```

please see [**codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jxIiC) for details